# Send body in GET request using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I have seen so many threads on stackoverflow with this question, only for the answers to fizzle out into something completely different to what is being asked. I know its bad practice or not standard practice to submit body with a GET request.

But this is the situation.
I have an api, that takes custom headers for authorization as well as accepted data type.

The same api instead of accepting the 'productId' as a parameter as in all humanly built APIs that uses GET, this one takes the 'productId' as a json submitted in the body of the API.

```
{
'productId':'297552891'
}
```

I have tested it out in postman and it works.
How can i do this with jQuery or ajax or anything javascripty from the web page?

Thanks

Comment: GET requests do not have bodies. Why exactly is it so important to circumvent web standards and go contrary to what the protocols are expected to do?

Comment: @Taplar It does. And postman successfully submitted a body with my request. And am not doing this by choice. i dont have a choice. I gotta consume this api for our thing to work :/ For ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: Can you provide a link to the docs for this api?

Comment: @charlietfl this is an in house application that is run within an enterprise. Unfortunately no documentation is available. It takes "Access-Key" and "Content-Type" in header with the token and "application/json" as its values respectively. Also in postman under the Body tab, we set raw and JSON from the dropdown to send the json shown in the question.

Comment: OK but according to MDN docs  neither fetch() or XMLHttpRequest  support a body for GET and will make it null. What happens when you send as POST?

Comment: "Why can you not send it as a POST?" is more the question.

Comment: @Taplar the api doesn't accept a POST request. It only accepts a GET request.
I tried it in postman.

Comment: Then change the API.

Comment: @charlietfl according to the link I posted above it looks like its supported but it's not standard practice. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: @Taplar my man with the most lamest answers :P. This is the predicament I am in and I would've changed it had i got the chance, but here we're.

Comment: Well if the MDN docs are accurate regarding fetch() and XMLHttpRequest then you would probably need to use a server side proxy that can send the GET with a body. Can we assume you have tried using both and if so what did the body look like?

Comment: @charlietfl I have tried only using jquery ajax. And postman to test if the api worked. Haven't tried with fetch(). I tried with XMLHttpRequest, but when i checked with fiddler, the request didn't send any body.

Comment: So that suggests the mdn docs are accurate then. jQuery ajax just wraps XMLHttpRequest ( and possibly fetch() in newer versions??). It has no proprietary transport mechanism not provided by the browser. Would be the same for other libs like axios, superagent etc